# Array will fill with indeterminate values after first insert

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to save strings into the array and then print them but after the first record is saved the whole array is (according to Visual Studio debugger) filled with nonsense. What am I doing wrong?

```
int saveRecord(int ixA, int ixB, int length, int* ocupied, char**arr)
{
  char r[50];
  sprintf(r,"%d: %d - %d", length, ixA, ixB);
  arr[*ocupied] = r;
  (*ocupied)++;
  return 0;
}
int printRecords(int ocupied, char** arr)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ocupied; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }
  printf("Options: %d\n", ocupied);
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  int length = 0, ixA = 0, ixB = 0;
  int* ocupied;
  int a = 0;
  ocupied = &a;
  char r[50] = "";
  char *arr[250000];
  for (int i = 0; i < 250000; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = "";
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &ixA, &ixB, &length);
    saveRecord(ixA, ixB, length, ocupied, arr);
  }
  printRecords(*ocupied, arr);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly if you expect anyone to read it all.

Comment: In `saveRecord`, you assign the local array `r` to `arr[]`. That array goes out of scope when you leave the function and therefore is invalid when you print it. You must either make your array an arry of arrays or you must allocate memory and copy the strings (and free them later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `saveRecord`:

```
char r[50];
sprintf(r,"%d: %d - %d", length, ixA, ixB);
arr[*ocupied] = r;
```

You're setting a value in your array to `r`, which is a local array.  In this context, `arr[*ocupied]` contains a pointer to the first element of `r`.  When `saveRecord` reuturns, `r` goes out of scope, so the pointer you saved off now points to invalid memory.  Returning a pointer to a local variable and subsequently dereferencing it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Since you want this data to persist outside of the function, you need to dynamically allocate memory instead of using a local variable:

```
// find out exactly how much space is needed
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d: %d - %d", length, ixA, ixB);
arr[*ocupied] = malloc(len + 1);
snprintf(arr[*ocupied], len + 1, "%d: %d - %d", length, ixA, ixB);
```